# Tape up plastic without a ladder

Tags: home, adhesive, weather

I want to put up some plastic to temporarily block a leaky window sill, about fifteen feet off the ground.

I'm thinking of using masking tape.

Are there any tools I could use to do this?    I do have an ordinary step ladder that goes up about 6 feet but nothing bigger.

Comment: I had a wild and crazy idea: rent the proper sized ladder.

Comment: I actually have one but it's on a steep slope and too dangerous to use

Answer (score 1):

Though I've used bamboo poles and pole-saws *sans* saw to tape objects overhead, I find it tricky to press the tape into place all along its edge. It would be easier with an assistant, so that one pole can hold the plastic sheet while another pole presses the tape down.

BTW, first dry the windows-sill where you're applying tape, so that it will stick. Also, you can form the bottom of the sheet into a funnel so that water can be collected in a bucket. This helped save our flooring after a snow dam forced water into the house.

Comment: How did you unroll the tape?   What sort of tape and plastic did you use?  Thanks!

Comment: First I opened the plastic sheeting and put duct tape along one edge, with about half the sticky part exposed. Then I pushed the edge with tape on the window sill. It sometimes slipped off after a while, and left sticky residue which was cleaned off with solvent, but it funneled the water into a bucket rather than the floor.